# Making an element draggable without jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build an image cropper similar to Twitters - http://jsfiddle.net/yarKr/1/. What I'm stuck on is the ability to drag the image. What is the best way to do this **without resorting to jquery ui**?

```
<div class="canvas">
    <span class="window"></span>
    <img src="http://www.dailystab.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/katy-perry-esquire-4.jpg" class="draggable" />
</div>
```

I want to be able to move drag the image around inside the .canvas div.

Comment: if you're not concerned about old browsers, use HTML5 drag-drop.

Comment: It's a good chunk of code, but nothing special to it. Listen for a mousedown, find and persist the current offset and mouse event pageX/pageY, set position absolute, listen for mousemoves, calc delta from original mouse position, set updated position to original offset + the delta. Listen for the mouseup to stop the mousemove listeners.

Comment: this article might help you get started: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this will work: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSL5D/3/)**

```
var TheDraggable = null;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.draggable').on({
        mousedown: function () { TheDraggable = $(this); },
        mouseup: function () { TheDraggable = null; }
    });

    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {

        if (TheDraggable) {

            TheDraggable.css({'top': e.pageY, 'left': e.pageX});
        }
    });
});
```

And then for the CSS you add this: `.draggable { position:absolute; }`

You could rewrite this and add some form of easing on the repositioning, change the cursor or add a more precise starting point based on where the initial click happened on the picture but overall, that should get you started.

Comment: Noobs (like me) hoping for a complete solution will be disappointed by it not having the starting point factored in :/

Answer (score 1):

How about, while dragging, making the position absolute and setting it to or near the position of the mouse?

Comment: Perhaps this is not so much an answer as a VERY valuable comment for the accepted answer? I tried the answer and it is very unsatisfying, given that when trying to drag a <div>, it jumps to put its top left corner under the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

This is mine.
http://jsfiddle.net/pd1vojsL/

3 draggable buttons in a div, dragging constrained by div.

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <button id="button1" class="button">Drag me</button>
    <button id="button2" class="button">Drag me</button>
    <button id="button3" class="button">Drag me</button>
</div>
<div id="log1"></div>
<div id="log2"></div>
```

Requires JQuery (only):

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').mousedown(function(e) {
        if(e.which===1) {
            var button = $(this);
            var parent_height = button.parent().innerHeight();
            var top = parseInt(button.css('top')); //current top position
            var original_ypos = button.css('top','').position().top; //original ypos (without top)
            button.css({top:top+'px'}); //restore top pos
            var drag_min_ypos = 0-original_ypos;
            var drag_max_ypos = parent_height-original_ypos-button.outerHeight();
            var drag_start_ypos = e.clientY;
            $('#log1').text('mousedown top: '+top+', original_ypos: '+original_ypos);
            $(window).on('mousemove',function(e) {
                //Drag started
                button.addClass('drag');
                var new_top = top+(e.clientY-drag_start_ypos);
                button.css({top:new_top+'px'});
                if(new_top<drag_min_ypos) { button.css({top:drag_min_ypos+'px'}); }
                if(new_top>drag_max_ypos) { button.css({top:drag_max_ypos+'px'}); }
                $('#log2').text('mousemove min: '+drag_min_ypos+', max: '+drag_max_ypos+', new_top: '+new_top);
                //Outdated code below (reason: drag contrains too early)
                /*if(new_top>=drag_min_ypos&&new_top<=drag_max_ypos) {
                    button.css({top:new_top+'px'});
                }*/
            });
            $(window).on('mouseup',function(e) {
                 if(e.which===1) {
                    //Drag finished
                    $('.button').removeClass('drag');
                    $(window).off('mouseup mousemove');
                    $('#log1').text('mouseup');
                    $('#log2').text('');
                 }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If two questions are so similar you can repost an answer verbatim, you should flag to close one as a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 0):

### Drag icon - less jumping

[image: move icon you can use] 
Borrowing from frenchie's answer I have to create a movable popup on the fly. Have to add dragability to the object after it's created. This not flawless - any faster than a slow drag and the cursor leaves the  behind until you let go, at which point the `<div>` then snaps and sticks to the cursor movements until you click again.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<input type="button" value="pop" onclick="pop('NN')" id="btnNN"><!-- NN is the query rownumber -->
<b style="display:none;" id="protoContent">
<div id="divdrag~">
    <img style="float:left;" id="drag~">
    my form <input id="inp1_~">...
</div>
</b>

<!-- language: lang-js -->
var TheDraggable = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        if (TheDraggable) {
            TheDraggable.css({'top': e.pageY-15, 'left': e.pageX-15});
        }//"-15" gets the cursor back on img inside the <div>
    });
});
var gOpenPop="";
function pop(NN){
    if(gOpenPop!=""){
        document.getElementById("divdrag"+gOpenPop).style.display="none";//hide opened
        if(gOpenPop==NN){
            gOpenPop="";
            return;
        }
    }
    gOpenPop=NN;
    //add div after the button
    $("#btn"+NN).after(
        //get div w/ form, replace of any "~"s with argument NN
        $("#protoContent").html().replace(/~/g,NN)
    );
    //ojb created, now bind click for dragability to the img
    $('#drag'+NN).on(
        {mousedown: function () {TheDraggable = $("#divdrag"+NN); },//
        mouseup: function () { TheDraggable = null; }
    });
    ...
}
```