# Why is there lag in javascript when objects follow the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

For example, when using jquery ui draggable (http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) the object follows the mouse rather than moving with the mouse. It seems like there is a one frame difference in position.

Why is that? Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: JS/DOM is pretty "far" from the CPU - therefore results will vary depending on the user's machine. I experience no lag on an a Core I7.

Comment: It's a feature, not a bug

Comment: @frenchie could you elaborate on that? I'm not claiming it's a bug, I am mostly wondering why it's happening and whether you can work around it?

Comment: @mdenchev: if you're really concerned about performance then go native js and that should solve this issue. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776150/making-an-element-draggable-without-resorting-to-jquery-ui This should get you started.

Comment: i think what you are saying is the easing transition of the box.. it somehow feels as if the box is left behind.. is this what you are asking?

Comment: @reikyoushin Yes, I think so. Jonathan Lonowski put it nicely by using the verb "chasing" instead of lagging. I imagine his explanation is correct.

Comment: and if you don't use an easing function you wont have to deal with that 'chasing' issue..

Comment: @frenchie the jsfiddle there is even worse than jquery ui

Comment: jQuery UI is a dog, you can get a lot better performance with more efficient dnd code. most of the dnd routines out there suck, many of them sniff the browser each mousemove, but it is possible to do decently by using modern properties and minimal positioning code.

Comment: @Esailija: I hacked that jsFiddle together in just a few minutes with jQuery. My point is just that if performance is the issue then start with a lightweight solution (the one I linked to is about 10 lines) and use only native javascript.

Comment: It turns out it's possible to get desktop/native feel by using the HTML5 drag n drop API (no mousemove hacks). Now if it only was possible for other things as well to gain that feel..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation is *chasing* your mouse's movement because it has to wait for the [`mousemove` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mousemove).

And, while the event fires fairly rapidly as you move the mouse pointer, it still fires *after* the pointer has actually moved. So, the box' position is always being updated to where the pointer was if it's still in motion.

The event will also be throttled by the (mostly) single-threading of JavaScript. If the engine is busy, including with a previous trigger of the event, the most recent trigger will have to wait for the engine to again become idle.

And, counting those triggers as *frames*, jQuery also employs *easing* so the box' position doesn't jump around oddly when there are irregularly-spaced *frames*.

Comment: Excellent, I think this explains it quite nicely (if my understanding/assumptions are correct). It is basically forced to be one frame behind because the mousemove event is triggered post drawing the mouse and the div's position can't be updated until the frame after.

Comment: It is so horrible compared to dragging icons on the desktop, I just lost so much hope for web applications :(.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to build a more efficient function, but it more or less depends on the browser, and system. If your browser and/or your system is slow, then you will experience a lag while dragging or following the mouse.

I experienced no lag with the link you provided.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a processing power problem. Even when using a newly built gaming computer, there is still lag. Maybe I am not explaining what I mean by lag well enough. When you drag an icon on the desktop, it seems to be moving near perfectly with the mouse. When I drag a div in a browser, it seems to be a few microseconds behind the previous mouse position. I am wondering what could be causing this. Maybe the mouse cursor updates quicker than the js script gets executed? As in mouse updates 60 times per sec and browser updates 30 times per sec?